# Issues setting gradient image as UINavigationBar background

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set a gradient image background for my navigation bar. Code is like so:

```
extension CAGradientLayer {

    class func gradientLayerForBounds(bounds: CGRect, startColor: UIColor, endColor: UIColor) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.frame = bounds
        layer.colors = [startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor]
        return layer
    }
}
```

Then in my view controller:

```
func imageLayerForGradientBackground() -> UIImage{

        var updatedFrame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        updatedFrame.size.height += 20 //Status bar
        let layer = CAGradientLayer.gradientLayerForBounds(updatedFrame, startColor: UIColor(hexString: "5FD238")!, endColor: UIColor(hexString: "A5E589")!)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.bounds.size)
        layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image

    }
```

viewDidLoad:

```
   navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
   navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(imageLayerForGradientBackground(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

The issue is that all my views under the navigation bar are now pushed down by what look like the height of the navigation bar (as drawn badly in the diagram below):

[image]

Why is this happening? Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:

```
func setupDrawerView() {

        answerDrawerView = AnswerDrawerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - AnswerDrawerView.submitTabHeight, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height*0.75))
        answerDrawerView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(answerDrawerView)
    }
```

Comment: Try go storyboard and uncheck the `Adjust scroll view inset` or `Under top bar` see if it help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing whatever to do with the gradient. It's all about this line:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

As soon as you say that, the main view stops underlapping the navigation bar. Well, you've positioned your views absolutely instead of using auto layout, so since the Biology button was, let's say, 35 points down from the top of the main view, it is *still* 35 points down from the top of the main view — but the top of the main view is now at the bottom of the navigation bar. Hence the gap.

The moral: use auto layout! This kind of situation is exactly what it is for. Position your views in relation to the top layout guide, not the top of the main view, and all will be well.

Comment: Thanks for that Matt. Changed to the top layout guide and now there are no issues with the top spacing. However I have noticed something else (I've added it to the question under EDIT ^). I have a slide out view I use at the bottom of the controller. It is setup just to reveal the top with a button to animate it out. However for some reason that button is not showing now. It just doesn't show when I try to add the gradient. Anything I should be careful of here?